# Входит ли точка в график

Tags: python, алгоритм

Необходимо написать программу, которая определяет, попадает ли точка с заданными координатами `X, Y` в область, закрашенную на рисунке серым цветом.

**Я пытался сделать так:**

> Задал условия при которых если точка не попадает в закрашенную область
> то выводится, что не попадает, а остальные случаи проверяются по
> формуле окружности `((x - 0)**2 / R ** 2 + (y - 0) ** 2 / R ** 2 ) <= 1`.

Проблема в том что такой способ не подходит для закрашенной области в 4-й четверти. Как вывести формулу которая будет проверять точку в закрашенной области 4-й четверти?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для 4-й четверти должно выполняться 2 условия - точка внутри окр. R2 и Не внутри R1 при заданном диапазоне x и y (x > 0  и y < 0)

Comment: Показывайте код. Без кода здесь не помогают делать учебные заадания.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тут не нужен код, потому что вопрос не про код